# Errors while running job through cloudbees, on the org the deployment succeeds

Tags: deployment, git

We have are using cloudbees to deploy to salesforce using ant.

While deploying to an org we get the following error, but if we check on the sandbox, the deployment actually proceeds.

Because of the below issue the deployment jobs are failing.

Below is the stack trace of the logs

> [sf:deploy] Failed to check the status for request ID=0Af0D00000Bw9K0SAJ. Error: InfoNot a valid enumeration for type: class com.sforce.soap.metadata.DeployProblemType. Retrying...
>   [sf:deploy] Failed to check the status for request ID=0Af0D00000Bw9K0SAJ. Error: InfoNot a valid enumeration for type: class com.sforce.soap.metadata.DeployProblemType. Retrying...
>   [sf:deploy] Failed to check the status for request ID=0Af0D00000Bw9K0SAJ. Error: InfoNot a valid enumeration for type: class com.sforce.soap.metadata.DeployProblemType. Retrying...
>   [sf:deploy] Failed to check the status for request ID=0Af0D00000Bw9K0SAJ. Error: InfoNot a valid enumeration for type: class com.sforce.soap.metadata.DeployProblemType. Retrying...

Is there something missing in the git configuration?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the ant-salesforce.jar file with the latest, spring '19 version solved the problem.